# Making servers/IP addresses part of same domain

Tags: domain, domain-name-system

I have been working on a project for a client and need some advise.

It is cloud app that will be deployed on EC2 and for each user(domain that user keys in) during registration, we need to spin a new server.
We basically want to make all servers to be part of same domain.
For ex:
We roll out an app for a user example

```
I user   - sam.jondoe.com - 77.99.00.01
II user  - sugar.jondoe.com - 77.99.00.01 
III user - damn.jondoe.com - 77.99.00.02
```

How do we make sure -- each server spun for the user will some how be part of same domain
jondoe.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You add that A record or CNAME record for the new server to your DNS zone for jondoe.com.

Comment: Further to that, if you want it to happen automagically, set up a dynamic DNS zone and put appropriate keys with rights to update that zone onto the server template. Then have them add their own record when provisioning is complete.